# Convert character string to a Datetime

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I convert a character string to datetime?  I need to be able to subtract this character string from an actual date field.

2013-01-01 06:21:31

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`TO_DATE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function:

```
TO_DATE(column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Or, if it's just a string literal:

```
TO_DATE('2013-01-01 06:21:31', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Thank you @Anthony Grist.  I was not counting for the 'SS' on one of my fields.  Your help and knowledge is appreciated greatly.